# Есть простейший дефолтовый GWT-проект. Как с помощью Maven сделать из него WAR-ник?

Tags: java, gwt, maven

Добрый день.
Есть пустой Maven-проект с добавленной поддержкой фреймворка GWT. Если запускать приложение как приложение GWT - всё ок. Т.е. формируется страничка с дефолтовым текстом и кнопкой.
Но стОит мне добавить в **pom.xml** строку:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

- ничего не работает. Выскакивает пустая html-страница с ошибкой:

**Problem accessing /gwt2war.html. Reason: 
    Not Found**

Мой **pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>ru.javastudy</groupId>
<artifactId>gwt2war</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <gwt.version>2.6.0</gwt.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Структура проекта:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Перемести всё содержимое из каталога `/war` в `/src/main/webapp` (его у тебя нет). Плюс у тебя нет зависимости `gwt` в секции `dependencies`. Её нужно добавить

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
  <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```